# jQuery filter object by value with inconsistent index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object similar to

`var obj = { 'Earth': 1, 'Sky': 2, 'Tree': 3, 'Sand': 4 };`

I am trying to filter based on value using this

```
$.filter(obj,function(i, value){
  return value>3;
});
```

However this is returning empty.

Expected output
`{'Sand': 4 }`

Is there a way to filter by value, when the indexes of the objects cannot be consistently addressed and may vary.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I have updated it with expected output

Comment: You shouldn't use jQuery to do that. It's a easy operation do with native JavaScript and it will be faster too. Take a look on the answers bellow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this..

```
function filterObjectProperties(obj, filtercb){
    var ret = {};
    for(var p in obj)
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(p))
            if(filtercb(obj[p]))
                ret[p] = obj[p];
    return ret;
}

var obj = { 'Earth': 1, 'Sky': 2, 'Tree': 3, 'Sand': 4 };

var newObj = filterObjectProperties(obj, function(val){
    return val > 3;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dht2L55L/

Comment: Would .keys() be more efficient because a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well? I did not test this supposition.

Comment: you're right, it loops prototype properties as well, that's why I used `hasOwnProperty()`, which filters out the prototype properties.

Comment: you could use `keys()` as well, but it's less portable. you would need to include a polyfill for old browsers.

Comment: OK, thanks, here is a link to a polyfill for those needing it for keys https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys  Note I did up vote this as a pretty generic solution.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without `$.filter`:

```
var obj = { 'Earth': 1, 'Sky': 2, 'Tree': 3, 'Sand': 4 };
result = {};
for (var k in obj) {
    if (obj[k] > 3) {
        result[k] = obj[k];
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Would  `.keys()`  be more efficient because a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well?  I did not test this supposition.

Answer (score 1):

You could you JQuery.each(). To use JQuery.filter and JQuery.grep, I think your object should be formed different.

```
$(function(){

var obj = { 'Earth': 1, 'Sky': 2, 'Tree': 3, 'Sand': 4 };

var result = null;

$.each(obj, function(key, value) {
   if(value > 3){
   result = key;
   }
}); 

console.log(result);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as

```
var obj = { 'Earth': 1, 'Sky': 2, 'Tree': 3, 'Sand': 4 };

var result = Object.keys(obj)
    .filter(function(e) { return obj[e] > 3 })
    .reduce(function(object, property) { 
         return (object[property] = obj[property], object);
     }, {})
```

without any library

Answer (score 1):

There is no native `filter` to the `Object` object, but how about this:

```js
var obj = { 'Earth': 1, 'Sky': 2, 'Tree': 3, 'Sand': 4 };
newObject = {}
Object.keys(obj).map(function(value, index) {
    if (obj[value]>3){
       newObject[value] = obj [value]
    }
});
snippet.log(newObject);
// => {'Sand': 4 }
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = { 'Earth': 1, 'Sky': 2, 'Tree': 3, 'Sand': 4 };

function filterObj(obj, valueThreshold) {
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  var result = {};
  keys.forEach(function(key) {
    var value = obj[key];
    if (value > valueThreshold) {
      result[key] = value;
    }
  })
  return result;
}

console.log('obj: ' + JSON.stringify(obj));
var filteredObj = filterObj(obj, 3);
console.log('filterdObj: ' + JSON.stringify(filteredObj));
```